# Prevent users from using the program on more than one computer

Tags: python, tkinter, desktop-application, offline

I made an offline program by Python Tkinder and now I want to sell this program to customers, but I want to find a way to prevent the customer from using this program on more than one computer, I know that I can do that by using Mac Address or hardware part numbers, but the customer is impossible to give me this data
How can I do that

Comment: Unless you enforce the use of some sort of hardware key to use the program, then I don't see a way of doing this without connecting to the internet (and of course requiring your customers to be online at all times to use the program). If the customer agrees to provide you with information identifying a specific computer they intend to use to access the program, you could add code to your program to only run when it detects that signature on the hosting device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109997/how-do-you-protect-your-software-from-illegal-distribution

Answer (score 0):

you may use `mac address`, (*which is different in every case*) to specify each single device.
For eg,

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
import os

def welcome():
    print('welcome user!')

purchased = false; # this will be declared true after payment.

if ((not os.path.exists('devId')) and purchased):
    # activation after payment
    open('devId', 'wt').write(str(get_mac()));
    welcome();
elif (open('devId', 'rt').read() == get_mac()):
    print('Purchase before using!')
    exit()
else:
    welcome();
```