# Securing a .NET Application

Tags: .net, security, obfuscation, reverse-engineering

#### Duplicate:

> [Protecting .NET Code from Reverse Engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering/)

We've recently released a small application and this weekend I found a cracked version of it on `Piratebay` that had the registration checking removed, so the app ran as if it was a registered version.

Apart from using a code obfuscation tool (which doesn't seem to be that hard to get around), are there any standard things we should be doing to make our .NET applications more difficult to crack?