# How to create own dotnet obfuscator

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I know that dot net dlls and exe contain their assemblies with them so every body can extract code from it. So please tell me how can i create my own .net obfuscator and if there exist any other way to protect my application to deassemble. and plez dont give me link of any paid obfuscator. i would prefer code sample in c# or vb.net

Comment: Building one of these is a serious undertaking.  That's why they're not cheap.  If your code is so important that you feel the need to obfuscate it, why not spring for an established one?

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651291/securing-a-net-application/651375#651375

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to understand some of the technical details of obfuscation I'd recommend reading the series of blog posts by Paul Mason. The series is called "Protecting your precious code" and you can find it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110501142447/http://blog.paul-mason.co.nz/tag/protectingyourpreciouscode).

It's linked with a project called [NCloak](http://code.google.com/p/ncloak/), this is open so you can download the source and take a look yourself if you want.

But I have to agree with others, this isn't easy and so you are probably better off buying a commercial product. As Paul says in several of his articles there are ways round most techniques, it's just a case of how much time someone wants to spend doing it.

But if you want to learn for you own education, then go-ahead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the site no longer exists :'(

Comment: I modified the link to use a mirror found on archive.org. Enjoy !

Comment: These resources are currently unreachable! :/

Answer (score 3):

There are several free ones available -- http://www.csharp411.com/net-obfuscators/ is one list.

Are you looking for something specific that available non-paid ones don't do?

Comment: Doug R has a good point -- if it's that important to protect, what's 3k or so to do it?

Comment: first of all thanks for giving me link for free obfuscators. but as i told u i want to create my own obfuscator so i need a open source application's link which i can use to create my own obfuscator by extending it.

Comment: But *why* do you want to create your own obfuscator rather than using an existing one?  Is it for learning purposes?  If you tell people why you specifically want to create your own they may be able to direct you towards specific appropriate resources or provide appropriate help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not cheap or easy to write a obfuscator.

If you are paid to develop code, I would seriously consider buying one.

That aside, there is nothing you can do to stop a determined person from access your IP, if you ship it in .exe form. All you can do is slow down a casual developer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [BitHelmet](http://www.bithelmet.com) obfuscator. for the price, I think it is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscation isn't about stopping people extracting the IL from your compiled units - if the runtime can find it, so can anyone who really wants to look at it.

Instead, obfuscation is about making it difficult for people to use that knowledge - for example, making it difficult to decompile the IL into readable source code.

Comment: please give me any idea that how to protect my exe of .net

Answer (score 0):

We must have to use obfuscator and if we are releasing commercial product then it more required. It protects us from unauthorized decompilation and reverse engineering of software. You can use various free as well paid obfuscators. Also for full proof protection you need to use copy protection to prevent unauthorised destrubution.

You can check free obfuscator. This is which I am using to protect my applications.

[FxProtect - Free .Net Obfuscator](http://www.maycoms.net)