# How Can I Run Lua Script With C#?

Tags: c#, github, lua

I Want Make A Lua Obfuscator. And I Dont Know How To Do It With C#

Lua Obfuscator Open Source = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Direnta/LuaSeel/master/obfuscator.lua

I Want Code Like This:

```
public string code;
code = lua("print('Hello' + textBox1.Text + '!')");
textBox2.Text = code;
```

Please Help Me

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857685/how-to-create-own-dotnet-obfuscator

Comment: Please Don't Write In Title Case Like This.

Comment: To run Lua script in C#, you need DynamicLua or NLua