# How to protect my code

Tags: c#, obfuscation, source-code-protection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Securing a .NET Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651291/securing-a-net-application)
>   [Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)

I am creating a c# application and i
    want to hide the code of that c#      application. When i use reflector
    for    my application exe / dll it,
    shows    all the code of that dll / exe.

1. I want    to hide the code of
   that dll and exe    . Can anyone
   tell me how to hide that    code ?
2. I came to know about
   "Dotfuscator" which makes it a little harder
   to understand the code in the DLL. Does anyone
   have a better answer than this option ?
3. I tried
   to open many DLLs by reflector but
   while opening some DLLs i get
   error messages that the CLI header is missing or
   something like that. Can I make use of that trick to hide code of that DLL ?

**Language : "(C#)"**

Pls help me on this issue...

or any other method without using obfuscators? I dont want to invest money in buying obfuscators so any free obfuscator (reliable)... just tell me the name.