# adding trial with time limitation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how can i add a trial with random serials or single serial and once it get registered expire it after 6-12 months....and also if user change its clock time to some day back it remains expire.....

Comment: You should read these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651291/securing-a-net-application/651375#651375 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651291/securing-a-net-application/651375#651375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the articles posted in the comment by @JoelCoehoorn first.

If you ***really*** want to pursue this after reading the articles, I believe that .NET Licensing might hold an answer to you.

http://windowsclient.net/articles/Licensing.aspx

You would essentially set up your main form as a licensed class.