# How can we make this code run with option strict on?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1  
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblSystemSerialNumbers.Text = SystemSerialNumber()
        lblCpuIds.Text = CpuId()
    End Sub

    Private Function SystemSerialNumber() As String
        ' Get the Windows Management Instrumentation object.
        Dim wmi As Object = GetObject("WinMgmts:")

        ' Get the "base boards" (mother boards).
        Dim serial_numbers As String = ""
        Dim mother_boards As Object = wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_BaseBoard")
        For Each board As Object In mother_boards
            serial_numbers &= ", " & board.SerialNumber
        Next board
        If serial_numbers.Length > 0 Then serial_numbers = serial_numbers.Substring(2)

        Return serial_numbers
    End Function

    Private Function CpuId() As String
        Dim computer As String = "."
        Dim wmi As Object = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
            "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
            computer & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim processors As Object = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

        Dim cpu_ids As String = ""
        For Each cpu As Object In processors
            cpu_ids = cpu_ids & ", " & cpu.ProcessorId
        Next cpu
        If cpu_ids.Length > 0 Then cpu_ids = cpu_ids.Substring(2)

        Return cpu_ids
    End Function
End Class
```

This code will retrieve the CPU id and the motherboard id. How do I ensure that this will work even when option strict is on.

Why this could be a problem?

Well, let's see. The type of wmi is Object. That wmi do not necessarily support methods like InstancesOf, and SerialNumber

So how can we pull this out?

I think object that we got from GetObject is not just pure object. I think we should ctype or direct cast it to a more appropriate type. That more appropriate type will support methods like InstancesOf, SerialNumber, etc.

However what are the appropriate types?

Comment: Did you try to change the GetObject and use the ManagementObjectSearcher and its classes?

Comment: I don't even understand what it means

Comment: The type of wmi is com objects by the way. Is there a wrapper class where I can do ctype to? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ManagementObjectSearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) from the WMI classes hosted inside the System.Management.dll assembly.
(And you need to add the appropriate reference).

In this way you could write the SystemSerialNumber as

```
Private Function SystemSerialNumber(computer As String) As String

    Dim wmi = New ManagementObjectSearcher(computer & "\root\cimv2", "select * from Win32_BaseBoard")

    Dim boards = New List(Of String)()
    For Each board In wmi.Get()
        Dim temp = board.Properties("SerialNumber").Value?.ToString()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(temp) Then
            boards.Add(temp)
        End If
    Next board
    Return String.Join(", ", boards)
End Function
```

The CpuId function is a bit more complex because you want to set the Impersonate flags but it is still possible to write a method around the NET wrapper classes for WMI interfaces

```
Private Function CpuId(computer As String) As String
    Dim cpu = New List(Of String)()

    Dim options = New ConnectionOptions()
    options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate

    Dim scope = New ManagementScope(computer & "\root\cimv2", options)
    scope.Connect()

    Dim query = New ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
    Dim wmi = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)
    For Each m As ManagementObject In wmi.Get()
        Dim temp = m.Properties("ProcessorId").Value?.ToString()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(temp) Then
            cpu.Add(temp)
        End If
    Next
    Return String.Join(", ", cpu)
End Function
```