# Is there a way to prevent users from sending false messages to server?

Tags: networking, exe, multiplayer

I'm currently writing a multiplayer game with network interactions (obviously). Is there a way to store some sort of encryption key within the executable so that I can signed any outgoing messages to the server such that the server knows the message is coming from the client code itself, not a cheater?

Sorry there's no code to go along with this question. I'm forging into unknown territory with this question in regards to my experience.

Comment: As the recording and movie industries have discovered, there's no encryption you can physically put in someone else's hands and have it still remain secure with a determined enough attacker.

Comment: What do you mean by the recording and movie industries specifically?

Comment: Look at what happened with DVD encryption.

Answer (score 0):

No. While it might be very difficult to do, it is possible to figure out your encryption method.

The potentially easiest way that they could get your encryption method is through decompiling your code, but this is much harder with some languages than others. Java and C# apparently can be decompiled to high-level readable code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800439/what-language-will-protect-my-source-code) question covers that topic.