# password protect asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, security, copy-protection

I have built an ASP.NET application that needs to be password protected. This application will be installed on multiple offline computers, and we need to make sure that when being installed it requires a password. But even if it requires a password, someone can easily copy the database and the published folder and duplicate the application on their system right?

I need a way to prevent this. Any ideas? It should only work on laptops that we have installed it on.

Comment: Just to confirm : you have a web application installed like a client application on individual client machines?

Comment: The machines are already offline, can you lock them down even further? (e.g. the person only has access to a browser)

Comment: Just as a tip. This kind of requirements should be best considered *before* creating the app. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a licensing tool like any other client app.  Check the license key during app startup and occasionally during the runtime.  Look at this post for ideas: [Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering/651375#651375)