# How to change compiled application name?

Tags: string, rename, compiled

My colleague got the assignment to find a way to change the name of a compiled application where the main form title has a missing character. We figured this might be possible through changing the string somewhere in the binary, but we couldn't even find the exact title string in the file using a hex editor. We don't have source code available, but the application was supposedly written in C#.

Is there a way to edit a form title and keep the rest of the application working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you de-compile your binary, make the change to the source and recompile? http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Also see [C# Decompilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480091/c-sharp-decompilers)