# How to extract .dll file in c#?

Tags: c#, dll, decompiler

I am new to .NET application development. Involving one project, there are three modules like Interface layer, Business layer, and Data layer; I built these and I got .dll file.

But I lost the source code of one .dll file.

I'd like to extract the .dll and get the same source code. Is it possible to extract my source code from the .dll file?

Comment: Search for c# decompiler: http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Try [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).  Note that this will get you a source-code *representation* of the DLL, but the original code is **gone** (be more careful with your sourcecode next time!)  Local variable names and comments, for example **cannot** be recovered.

Comment: http://www.decompiler.net/  download a free evaluation version as well

Comment: What code versioning system are you using? Perhaps another question can help you identify a good backup scheme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Decompilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480091/c-sharp-decompilers)

Answer (score 6):

I really like [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), it's free and easy to use.

Used it for same purposes

Comment: Try commenting instead.

Comment: Or .NET Reflector, but this is not free, http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Answer (score 1):

Try [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net), an open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler (it  requires the .NET Framework 4.0).