# Constructor with no definition

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I'm new to .Net and I just saw this code that doesn't make sense to me (slightly abridged):

```
namespace test
{
    public class sub : super
    {
        public sub(string text);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a constructor that takes an argument, but does not implement a definition. How does that work? My guess is that it somehow relates to the super class, but I dont understand how, and I havent been able to find anything on Google.

Edit: Im running this in VS2010, and I just noticed that the tab has `[from metadata]` in the title. Perhaps this is why?

Comment: that code doesn't compile.are you using a decompiler to see this code?

Comment: @Selman22 I wouldnt expect it to, seeing as super was never defined. Either way, I figured out why this is happening - its because Im looking at metadata and not actual sourcecode

Comment: This is just the decompiled "interface" of your code (this is what "from metadata" means)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If from the metadata, it's not going to show you the implementation of the methods.

Answer (score 6):

That's not code.

That's text that *looks somewhat like code* based on the metadata in the assembly.  You'll see this when the IDE doesn't have access to the source code in question (For example, you press <kbd>F12</kbd> on a method in a referenced assembly.)  It provides the method signatures, properties, fields, etc from the types, without providing any of the actual implementation.

As written, the code you posted wouldn't even compile in C#.

Comment: Note, if you do want to see the code you will need to get a [decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480091/c-sharp-decompilers) or if you are looking for a class built in to the .NET runtime itself you can also see the source for it on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like code but it is text based on the metadata in the assembly. It means that the IDE is unable to access the source code in question.