# How to protect source code in .dll assembly in .NET, in particular C sharp code

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, protected, disassembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)

Hi All,

There are tools that can allow you to see the source code of dll assembly. I want to find out how to prevent that, so that C sharp source code is protected.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into [Code Obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code). I have used [dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview) for .net and has worked well.