# Why can we decompile .NET assemblies easily?

Tags: c#, decompiler

Why can we decompile .NET assemblies easily?

What's the main reason we can decompile .NET EXE files easily?

There are much software that I can use to obfuscate my application code, but why does it need to obfuscate for protection? Couldn't Microsoft make it difficult to know basically? May the main reason be that .NET code should turn into IL code? Is this true?

Comment: you may want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering) first

Comment: back to the basic question, do you want to lose/expose the code of your applications/techniques/researches to others? Intelligence Property?

Comment: also it might be an interesting read to you: "CLR via C#" by Jeffrey Richter (ISBN 0735627045).

Comment: Also: note this isn't very different to java; it isn't a question of "couldn't make it difficult" - simply: *that is not the requirement* (and would be a false veneer of security)

Comment: Are you sure you aren't asking "why isn't the compiler obfuscating the code a little, for example by stripping the local variable names" or "why even in Release mode my code doesn't seem to be optimized very much?"

Comment: 4:09 into this interview with Vance Morrison, a key IL designer: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Vance-Morrison-CLR-Through-the-Years/

Answer (score 2):

IL code (which is what .NET assemblies contains) is a higher level (virtual) machine language (and much more simpler - stack based only, no registers, etc. as you have in a CPU) than the CPU assembly (x86, ARM, etc.) which is much more low level and not easy (as there are various registers, etc.).

So when the C# compiler compiles to IL code, it is much easier to construct (guess) the original C# code.

Comment: Is this answering the question?

Comment: The title says `why can we decompile .NET assemblies easily?` and as par that this answer does do justice to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't Microsoft do it? Because you can not protect your code against a determined hacker. Like the biggest software provider, they don't make built-in something like this, but they let you have a market of tools where you can choose the most apropriate tool for you based on your needs and pocket size.

Answer (score 0):

When you open up a .NET DLL with DotPeek or Reflector you are converting IL back into code in the language of your choice. It is important to visualise this as it won't give you back exactly the same code that was written, just code that would produce the same IL.

Comment: This IS a little nitpicking :-) You'll probably have code better formatted but without comments. Even on release mode the compiler doesn't introduce many changes.

Comment: There are a few places where it will optimise your code, which often come back looking a bit different. Simple statements don't change very much.

Comment: And sometimes it will just do the completely wrong thing (looking at you Reflector!).