# could obfuscated .Net C# Application be Decompiled?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, decompiler, deobfuscation

I have written a program in .net C# to encrypt some information.

To accomplish the task I used an array which contains confidential information.I need to know that is it possible to crack the exe.I mean can anybody get the array from the exe file.The array values are not shown in the application.I used community version of Dotfuscator which comes with Visual Studio.NET.
All I want to know that is it possible to extract the exe to access the member variables used in it.. ??

Comment: I would say yes, if you know how pretty much any exe is able to be decompiled. Failing that you could even use a hex editor to access the data.

Comment: I think the 'crack' word is not perfect on this context.But I didn't remember any better word at the moment.Editing is most appreciable.If any one understands what want to say then please edit the question. thanks in advance  :)

Comment: by confidential information do you mean "the key"?

Comment: @AbdurRahman No worries ;) +1 as this didn't deserve -4!

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering

Comment: @Piskvor Thanks for giving a perfect link..

Comment: The question should be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would be very easy to decompile the application. You might want to install and run [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) (or a similar equivalent) and see what gets exposed. Fundamentally, if there's sensitive information embedded in the application, it can always be found.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely yes, if you didn't encrypt the Exe by using Dotfuscator or any other protection software, the cracker not just can see your array variables, but can return the whole source code of your application.

Comment: Nitpick: Dotfuscator et al. provide *obfuscation* (hence the name), not encryption - in the hope that it will make understanding of the decompiled app harder. This is aimed more at program flow than at data structures contained therein.

Comment: @Nitpick: you are right, it should be obfuscation:), but keep in mind encryption for string is one of the features provided by Dotfuscator.

Comment: Well yes - but to keep the strings usable, Dotfuscator needs to insert the decryption code into the resulting application - which brings it back to "even more obfuscation". (I don't think that we're actually in disagreement)