# Tamper Protection on .NET Assemblies

Tags: .net, obfuscation

Many obfuscation tools today offer tamper protection. We gave it a try but it was not applicable in most of our real-world cases.

Does it worth to invest time in this technologies or the added protection level is something that hackers can break in minutes as all the rest?

References:

- [Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering/506301#506301)
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/features/
- http://www.9rays.net/Category/55-spicesnet-obfuscator.aspx
- http://xheo.com/products/code-protection/how-it-works

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All code that runs on the client can be changed and tampered with, the tools will only make it a little harder to do. First of all find out if there is a business case in `tampering` your code anyway. If so, then decide if you should ship it at all or provide the critical code as a service.