# Asp.net Server control licensing protection

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, licensing

This question is related to the below article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479017.aspx

According to the article we need to create an EncryptedLicenseProvider and validate the license using LicenseManager.Validate(typeof(EncryptedLicensedLabel)) method.

What if the person who downloads my control manages to decompile the control and recompile it by skipping this check. Is there a way I can prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t stop people from cracking your software! You simply can’t.

Here is a nice article on why it does not make sense to worry about:

http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2008/10/19/my-views-on-software-piracy/

And here about obfuscation:

[Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)

You can also check the signature/hashsum, etc of your control assembly in your license.