# VB.Net code to make an Windows application that runs for One year only

Tags: vb.net

I need to install VB.net windows application in client's environment.
It is fully for one year validated application. 
After one year the client may change the system date and run the application without informing us for renewal.

**How to validate for one year date, if the client changes the system date and the application will popup a Message that
"Please dont change the system date... for running application,... Go for Renewal"**

Comment: use an internet time server to get the correct date. Also, you can add an `Expired` flag to the data you save, and set it to True once the time passes (and DONT reset it), once it is expired your app can ignore the system clock because you have already detected it as Expired.  The complexities have just started though...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering/651375#651375

Answer (score 0):

generally speaking, you should be doing a call out to a service to then truly be able to trap any mishaps the client tries to do (changing system date etc...) and so your service will enable or disable the application.

you may argue that the client could disable the internet/network access - ok, but even the suggestion given by @Plutonix will not work as it will not be able to access the internet to get the time.

therefore you need to code logic in your client app to determine if you can access the internet at startup...if so, great - if not - close the app.