# Make a c# code non decompilable?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it is possible to decompile a **.net binary** application? and I found out that is easy as a piece of cake!

This is wired. why would Microsoft NOT protect customer source code binaries?

At least why it is so easy to decompile even with **orginal** variable names and etc.

I know that in PHP there is a way to encode your source code that nobody can read that. I don't know if its impossible to decompile BUT at least it is not as easy as JetBrains or ILSpy

So my main Question is here:

**IS THERE ANY WAY TO ENCODE YOUR SOURCE CODES IN .NET (C#)?**

Comment: you can obfuscate but you can't hide the code.

Comment: Its duplicates all the way down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might follow ways of protecting your code from being reverse engineered, stolen or even cracked. **Obfuscate** your code to make it hard to understand when viewed via a reflector. Use a custom or third party **packer** and pack executables encyrpted.

But there will always be someone who can break into your code. This topic is covered deeply in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)

Answer (score 0):

You can always disassemble it because all programming languages get compiled to machine code. so you will always be able to get to machine code and from there to assembly. So you can make it harder to read for the people that are after the code. So no you're not able to stop people from seeing your code