# WCF Service Hosting on client premises

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-hosting

I have to create an application which communicate with DB through WCF Service. WCF service will be hosted on client's server.It will be an intranet environment. I want to use NetTCPBinding to get the performance benefit.

If i use IIS7 to host my service on client's server, then source code is available to client. I don't want to make source available to client.

My question is.
How do I host my service so source code would not available to client?

While we are hosting WCF service in IIS 7 can we provide only WCf service exe? If yes then how Please explain.

Comment: Will Self hosting helps in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering)

Comment: No it won't. You cannot prevent your net assemblies from being dissasembled. Anyway, why do you care if this happens?

Comment: I am not talking about Obfuscation and i am not bothered about this. When we host our application in IIS we provide complete code not exe. I want to know is it possible to create exe of WCF service and host with in the IIS7 or above?

Comment: What complete code? Just compile it into an assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is quite detailed guide](http://dotnetmentors.com/hosting-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding-or-netnamedpipebinding-in-iis.aspx) of how to host WCF service in IIS.
No need to put your source code there.