# Migration from Dotfuscator to .NET Reactor - what obfuscation attributes are supported?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, dotfuscator, net-reactor

Obfuscation attributes used in existing code obfuscated using Dotfuscator:

```
[Obfuscation(Feature = "controlflow", Exclude = true)]
[Obfuscation(Feature = "renaming", Exclude = true)]
[ObfuscationAttribute(Exclude = true, ApplyToMembers = false)]
[ObfuscationAttribute(Exclude = true, ApplyToMembers = true)]
```

For some reason the code shall be obfuscated with .NET Reactor.

What obfuscation attributes are supported by .NET Reactor?

Comment: And what exactly is the question? Supported by what? Are you trying to migrate from Dotfuscator to .NET Reactor?

Comment: Excactly, do I have to check each attribute individually ? Is it kind of optional and up to the tool what happens ?

Comment: I have no idea about Dotfuscator or .NET Reactor but I was trying to understand your question. I think you should rephrase the title and add the actual question to the body. I have submitted an edit to do just that.

Comment: @Werner why not to ask their support, after all you pay for it...

Answer (score 3):

There is a [little helper tool](https://www.eziriz.com/downloads/DeclarativeProtectionHelper.zip) for .NET Reactor which helps you to find/set the right obfuscation attributes.

[image]

Comment: I use the following command line:
-antitamp 1 -control_flow_obfuscation 1 -flow_level 9 -prejit 1 -necrobit 1 -file  %release_dir%%%i.dll  -mapping_file 1    -snkeypair "%snk_file%"
Will the attribute override  command line,  or the command line will override the attribute declaration.

Comment: As long as the assembly attribute is set the type/member obfuscation attributes have a higher priority. This way you can apply specific protection features even if the features are not enabled via command-line.