# Protect code of WPF application written in .Net 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know this question is asked many times, I read every question but didn't find solution for my case.
Our team made an application in .Net 4.7.2 and in few days we have to deploy it. We are using web services, so even if user cracks license system, they won't be able to access services. Our only concern is to prevent its duplication (someone can resell under his brand and this happened to our previous versions) as these web services(simple CRUD operations) are very easy to implement, so someone can change URL to there servers and duplicate these services. For protection against this, we are using encrypted calls to server. Problem we are facing now is to protect this encryption algorithm and obfuscation is not enough for this.
Again our only concern is to protect code. Sorry for bad English.
I know about .Net Reactor but there are many unpacker that can unpack .Net reactor protected application. I don't know if these unpacker work on current version.

- Should I use .Net Reactor?
- Is there any solution out there to convert .Net 4.7 code to native code or any other way to prevent this(except for obfuscation or Ahead Of Time Compilation)?

Comment: Other than obfuscation (which will make things harder for a potential thief, but not impossible) you are basically out of luck. Whatever solution you take, the task might make the hacker the life harder, but you can't really prevent it. If people really sell your stuff (more or less openly) under their name, you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you distribute can/will be analized (even copied/cloned) by all sorts of people, no way around that. Even only distributing compiled binaries is not a real hurdle for a determined adversary. Semi-compiled languages like Java's JVM or .NET often keep a lot of source information in the binary, to the point that sometimes decompiling to understandable source is more or less automatic. Source obfuscation can help a bit here, but that introduces another step (and possibly introduce bugs!), but an attacker will probably only be interested in localized swaths of code anyway.

If the services are "easy to duplicate", as you state, I wonder if they are really that valuable. Most extremely valuable 'net services use simple, even well known and publicly available protocols (as in "download a library to use our services here") to access them, but if I'd create my own clone of e.g. YouTube I'll get nowhere, the value is *not* in the interface but in the service offered.

Re keep encryption secret: *Never* forget [Kerckhoffs' rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auguste_Kerckhoffs). In particular, homebrew encryption is usually ridiculously easy to break, getting at the exact algorithm is possible with some ingenuity even if it is only in hardware (like the [MiFare card hack](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2537817/how-they-hacked-it--the-mifare-rfid-crack-explained.html)), and unless it has been carefully designed, it will be broken in short order. Do use the accepted cryptographic tools, like AES, Diffie-Hellman, RSA. Yes, it might be incur in some extra costs (in any case there are free/open source alternatives available for everything of interest), but it is much, much more secure than anything you could come up with.