# Prepare WPF app first release: Should change all projects configs?

Tags: wpf, desktop-application, release-management

I am preparing a WPF app to be released, I have about 5 modules (Class Libraries) along with the main app (Windows Application), should I change all the modules and the application build configurations from Debug mode to Release mode? or is it enough to only change the Main App build configuration mode to Release?

Answer (score 2):

Change all to `Release` with the main app as well and build. There is no reason to have debug code, for size and security, in released software.

Answer (score 2):

## Toolbar

You can refer to the toolbar and select specific configuration for the current solution. It will automatically change building configuration for the all projects included in the solution itself (in spite of any dependencies between projects).

[image]

In case if you cant see the configuration combobox in toolbar, try to add it using the **Standard Toolbar Options button**.

[image]

## Configuration Manager

Used for detailed building configuration management. Change configuration and platform options here both for one single project or the whole solution.
Menu bar/Build/Configuration Manager

[image]

## Security

Unfortunately or not, but there is no solution to ensure the complete security of the application. We can combine a bunch of different techniques, but thats still not secure enough.
Please refer to [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/651375/14119764), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506301/14119764) answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering) to get details.